# Trigger an event when system locks/unlocks on Windows XP

Tags: windows, scripting, time, tracking, python-idle

Please help me to find a way to track lock/unlock time on my WinXP machine. I've tried windows scheduler - it only logs logins, not locks. Any alternatives?

In Miranda's source code I saw implementation via IdleObject tracker, but this way is too long. May be an AutoIt script? Time tracking program (freeware)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Windows service you can get notification of login/logout/lock/unlock events via the `OnSessionChange` method. In C# you would do this:

```
 protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
 {
        switch (changeDescription.Reason)
        {
            case SessionChangeReason.SessionLogon:
                //Logon
                break;
            case SessionChangeReason.SessionLogoff:
                //Logoff
                break;
            case SessionChangeReason.RemoteConnect:
                //Remote Connect
                break;
            case SessionChangeReason.RemoteDisconnect:
                //Remote Disconnect
                break;
            case SessionChangeReason.SessionLock:
                //lock
                break;
            case SessionChangeReason.SessionUnlock:
                //Unlock
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Can I use this snippet from within a script, e.g. VB?

Comment: Well you need to create a Windows service to get the OnSessionChange hook, so you couldn't use this technique from a VB script directly. You could however implement a Windows service in VB though.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using Windows XP built in [eventtriggers.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/eventtriggers.mspx?mfr=true), which basically monitors one of Windows event logs for changes and allow you to trigger stuff based on criteria you specify. Since it is a log monitor it will usually trigger after a short delay

For example the following code that will call a BAT-file with a parameter depending on login/logout-related events (however, this is unfortunately not only actual user login/logouts but also system-related events and computer lock events)

```
eventtriggers.exe /create /tr "logout_occured" /l SECURITY  /eid 538 /tk "cmd /c c:\lockhandler.bat LOGOUT_OCCURED"
eventtriggers.exe /create /tr "login_occured" /l SECURITY  /eid 528 /tk "cmd /c  c:\lockhandler.bat LOGIN_OCCURED"
```

Comment: I executed above commands on Windows XP machine but batch file is getting executed/called only for unlock event and not for lock event. I am not sure about event id for lock event as there is no log entry in event viewer for lock event. Any Suggestion are most welcomed.

Comment: Vijaysing - The events are in the security log and it turns out I meant login/logout events (corrected my post above). These are sometimes triggered by locking/unlocking as well as actual login/logout. In the end I don't really use the eventtrigger solution anymore, since I cannot see what user triggered the event (something that one can see in the event viewer)

Comment: @Brummo What is your solution now?

Comment: I am afraid I don't have an automated solution anymore, since it didn't work properly for what I tried to achieve. Since my need wasn't that great, I just resorted to checking the Event log manually.

Answer (score 0):

Do check that CanHandleSessionChange property is  True or not ?
This will be checked from the designer view -> Property

Then use OnSessionChange function